# How to deploy jhipster application on standalone Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, jhipster

I'd like to deploy my application on tomcat just by copying war to /webapps folder and starting tomcat service. Now when I try I get this [stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/Ng1Xgj03). Database credentials are correct. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <hikaricp.version>2.4.1</hikaricp.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.1.0</assertj-core.version>
        <awaitility.version>1.4.0</awaitility.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <gatling.version>2.1.7</gatling.version>
        <gatling-maven-plugin.version>2.1.7</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.4.1</liquibase.version>
        <liquibase-slf4j.version>1.2.1</liquibase-slf4j.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate4.version>3.5</liquibase-hibernate4.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.0.0.CR1</mapstruct.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.3.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-sortpom-plugin.version>2.3.0</maven-sortpom-plugin.version>
        <metrics-spark-reporter.version>1.2</metrics-spark-reporter.version>
        <metrics-spring.version>3.1.2</metrics-spring.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1203-jdbc42</postgresql.version>
        <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <springfox.version>2.0.3</springfox.version>
        <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>
        <!-- Sonar properties -->
       (...)
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        (...)
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.sortpom</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sortpom-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-sortpom-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sort</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sortProperties>true</sortProperties>
                    <nrOfIndentSpace>4</nrOfIndentSpace>
                    <sortDependencies>groupId,artifactId</sortDependencies>
                    <sortPlugins>groupId,artifactId</sortPlugins>
                    <keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>
                    <expandEmptyElements>false</expandEmptyElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configFolder>src/test/gatling/conf</configFolder>
                    <dataFolder>src/test/gatling/data</dataFolder>
                    <resultsFolder>target/gatling/results</resultsFolder>
                    <bodiesFolder>src/test/gatling/bodies</bodiesFolder>
                    <simulationsFolder>src/test/gatling/simulations</simulationsFolder>
                    <!-- This will force Gatling to ask which simulation to run
                      This is useful when you have multiple simulations -->
                    <simulationClass>*</simulationClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireMavenVersion>
                            <message>You are running an older version of Maven. JHipster requires at least Maven 3.0</message>
                            <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
                        </requireMavenVersion>
                        <requireJavaVersion>
                            <message>You are running an older version of Java. JHipster requires at least JDK ${java.version}</message>
                            <version>[${java.version}.0,)</version>
                        </requireJavaVersion>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx256m ${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</destFile>
                            <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo runtime agent. -->
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after unit tests have been run -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.testresult.directory}/coverage/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <defaultOutputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources
                    </defaultOutputDirectory>
                    <processors>
                        <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                    </processors>
                    <options>
                        <mapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp>true</mapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp>
                        <mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>spring</mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>
                    </options>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/NScanner</url>
                    <defaultSchemaName></defaultSchemaName>
                    <username>NScanner</username>
                    <password></password>
                    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:pl.lodz.p.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</referenceUrl>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <logging>debug</logging>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-hibernate4.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--
                    This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only.
                    It has no influence on the Maven build itself.
                    Remove when the m2e plugin can correctly bind to Maven lifecycle
                -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            jacoco-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [0.7.4,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
             </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>fast</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>true</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev,fast</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.trecloux</groupId>
                        <artifactId>yeoman-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-frontend-build</id>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <buildTool>grunt</buildTool>
                                    <buildArgs>build --force --no-color</buildArgs>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <yeomanProjectDirectory>${project.basedir}</yeomanProjectDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp/dist</directory>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>.tmp</directory>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>node_modules</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- this is set to false because of https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2225 -->
                            <executable>false</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--spring.profiles.active=prod</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>INFO</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

I don't have this: `Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /data` exception when I remove elasticsearch from dependencies. All tomcat files are owned by tomcat user. I have no idea what can I do to fix errors on deploy. My standalone tomcat version is 8.5.4

Comment: Please post complete log, it's not sure that you have correctly set profile with corresponding application properties. If you are in prod profile, you must have installed an elasticsearch cluster and have a correct url configured in app properties. Also you didn't post enough details about JHipster config  and version.

Comment: Which log? I published complete `catalina.out` in question.

Comment: OK so now we know you're running dev profile with an old version of JHipster. When in dev, JHipster uses embbedded elasticsearch which needs  write access to /data or you can configure another path. Please fix this issue and consider upgrading JHipster.

Comment: I've got an error when I tried to upgrade. Here is separate question on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376354/error-on-jhipsterupgrade